# SQL - Splitting a row with week range into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure and data in the database table:

| ID | Year | StartWeek | EndWeek | AllocationPercent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2021 | 34 | 35 | 50 |
| 6 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 5 |

I need to split the multi-week rows into multiple single-week rows, and the end result should be:

| ID | Year | StartWeek | EndWeek | AllocationPercent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2021 | 34 | 34 | 50 |
| 5 | 2021 | 35 | 35 | 50 |
| 6 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 2021 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 2021 | 3 | 3 | 5 |

Any help with this would be highly appreciated! There are a lot of threads regarding splitting date ranges into multiple rows but I cannot seem to modify those to fit my use case. I know that most likely I need a tally table with the week numbers (which I already have).

Comment: (Do you need both `StartWeek` and `EndWeek` in the output? Seems redundant, I would expect `EffectiveWeek` or similar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think about this is, because we know the max weeknumber is 53, to generate the set of all possible week numbers, then outer join to that set each week in any source row that is within that range.

```
;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n <= 53
)
SELECT w.ID, 
       w.Year, 
       StartWeek = n.n, 
       EndWeek = n.n, 
       w.AllocationPercent
  FROM n
  INNER JOIN dbo.TableName AS w
  ON n.n BETWEEN w.StartWeek AND w.EndWeek
  ORDER BY w.ID, w.Year, n.n;
```

Results:

| ID | Year | StartWeek | EndWeek | AllocationPercent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2021 | 34 | 34 | 50 |
| 5 | 2021 | 35 | 35 | 50 |
| 6 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 2021 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 2021 | 3 | 3 | 5 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d6499e3431cdab413d9b5d5bf1a47ca)

Comment: Personally I would just go for a `VALUES` of all the numbers from `0` to `53` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b73418a356d70512633b3431ca28d7d

Comment: @Charlieface If you're going to manually type out all the numbers you may as well just create a permanent numbers table. I'm not a big fan of shoving 53 constants in a query every time, especially if that range could change later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive `cte` :

```
;with cte as (
      select t.id, t.year, t.startweek, t.endweek, t.AllocationPercent
      from t
      union all
      select id, year, startweek + 1, endweek, AllocationPercent
      from cte c
      where startweek < endweek
)
select id, year, startweek, startweek as endweek, AllocationPercent
from cte
order by id, startweek, endweek;
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1741211ad4dc63726093e90ad529b9f)

Comment: This recursive CTE query does not completely work - it splits the original first row into two.

However, the first row stays in the original format (StartWeek = 34 and EndWeek = 35) and the second row is correct (StartWeek = 35, EndWeek = 35).